# Exclude href links in search results using regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list, google-api

I'm trying to exclude certain links from my Google API search results.  I'm attempting to use a regular express pulled from a list of links_to_exclude.  This approach still outputs links that I don't want.

some of the links returned:

https://money.cnn.com/2018/08/21/technology/facebook-disinformation-iran-russia/index.html

https://www.cnn.com/videos/politics/2018/08/22/carl-bernstein-worse-than-watergate-egregious-trump-newday-sot-vpx.cnn

https://www.nytimes.com/2018/08/13/us/politics/peter-strzok-fired-fbi.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&clickSource=story-heading&module=first-column-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news

How do I exclude these links using regular expressions?

```
links_to_exclude = ['cnn.com', 'nytimes.com']

for item in search_terms:
results = google_search(item, api_key, cse_id, num=1)
for result in results:
    rtn_link = result.get('link')
    for link in links_to_exclude:
        regex = '((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)?({})\/([^\/]+)'.format(link)
        if re.search(regex, rtn_link):
            continue
        else:
            pprint.pprint(result.get('link'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex seems to be correct. I think you are just missing the `import re` on the script.

See here: https://ideone.com/Uzcf1K

```
import re

links_to_exclude = ['cnn.com', 'nytimes.com']
results = ['https://foo.bar', 'https://money.cnn.com/2018/08/21/technology/facebook-disinformation-iran-russia/index.html','https://www.cnn.com/videos/politics/2018/08/22/carl-bernstein-worse-than-watergate-egregious-trump-newday-sot-vpx.cnn','https://www.nytimes.com/2018/08/13/us/politics/peter-strzok-fired-fbi.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&clickSource=story-heading&module=first-column-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news']

for result in results:
    print "URL: " + result
    for link in links_to_exclude:
        regex = '((http[s]?|ftp):\/)?\/?([^:\/\s]+)?({})\/([^\/]+)'.format(link)
        if re.search(regex, result):
            print '  Matches: ' + link
        else:
            print '  Does not match: ' + link
```

**Output:**

```
URL: https://foo.bar
  Does not match: cnn.com
  Does not match: nytimes.com
URL: https://money.cnn.com/2018/08/21/technology/facebook-disinformation-iran-russia/index.html
  Matches: cnn.com
  Does not match: nytimes.com
URL: https://www.cnn.com/videos/politics/2018/08/22/carl-bernstein-worse-than-watergate-egregious-trump-newday-sot-vpx.cnn
  Matches: cnn.com
  Does not match: nytimes.com
URL: https://www.nytimes.com/2018/08/13/us/politics/peter-strzok-fired-fbi.html?hp&action=click&pgtype=Homepage&clickSource=story-heading&module=first-column-region&region=top-news&WT.nav=top-news
  Does not match: cnn.com
  Matches: nytimes.com
```

Comment: You're right, my code was correct.  The issue is being cause by my search results that are being returned from the Google API.  THANKS for doing a sanity check on my regex.